# How to use form input in controller function to enter authentication code to secure form submission (NOT VALIDATION BUT VERIFICATION) IN CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my controller page:

```
 function saveNewForm()
 {
   //----------- verifying code-------------------------
    $transactionCode = 0010; // any secret code
    echo "
         <input type='text' name='value'>
         <input type='submit' name='submit'>
         ";
    if($this->input->post('value') == $transactionCode){

        //----------- posting data from view--------------------
        $form = $this->input->post();
        $data = $form;
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $result = $this->user_model->saveNewTransaction($data);

        redirect('transactions');
    }
 }
```

I know there is some mistake in if statement that I am comparing `$this->input->post('value')` which is not actually coming from the FORM but it is already in the controller.

$form gets the data from view page which also have a FORM.

How do make this work fine.

I want to verify user by let him enter password to submit the form.

I have tried to use `onsubmit` in form but this code can be removed from inspect element on browser and unfortunately user can bypass that.

I am doing this for security purpose so that I can minimize the user to make changes in data using various techniques.

Comment: I have figured other way to complete this by sending transaction code from view page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this , but u can try this code

```
function saveNewForm()
{
$transactionCode = 0010; // any secret code
echo "
     <form action='' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='value'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit'>
     </form>
     ";
if(!empty($this->input->post('value')){
    if($this->input->post('value') <> $transactionCode){
        exit();
    }
}

$form = $this->input->post();
$data = $form;
$this->load->model('user_model');
$result = $this->user_model->saveNewTransaction($data);

redirect('transactions');


}
```

but when u are click submit the post data only have "value"

and for what "$form = $this->input->post();" ?

Comment: $form have the data coming from the view page which also have a form. and i have tried your code not working still, issue is it is not even showing the input box, it just executes all the `function saveNewForm()`

Comment: now it is showing input form but not doing anything if I enter correct code.